# Physics problem about kinematics & time differences (Source: #22- Krane, Halliday, Resnick)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time

> Question: On April 15 an airplane takes off at 4:40 P.M. from Belém, Brazil bound for Villamil, Ecuador (in the Galapagos). The plane lands at 8:40 P.M. Villamil local time. The sun sets at 6:15 P.M. in Belém (local time), and 7:06 P.M. in Villamil (local time). At what time during the ﬂight do the airplane passengers see the sun set?

I am trying to get the time difference betwen the two places since that is essential to solving the problem. However, the maximum I'm able to understand is this:

4 hours(difference in local times from arrival at Villamil and takeoff from Belem) = x + y

x = actual time it takes to go from Belem to Villamil

y = time difference between Belem and Villamil

How do you get x or y?

Comment: Hi Aditya; what options have you considered to calculate or look up the time difference between these places?

Answer (score 0):

The setting of the sun is the event we will use to calculate the time difference. Ignoring the effects of the tilting of the Earth's axis, places with the same local time see the sun set at the same time and those with different local times see it set at different times, the difference in the times at which the sun sets in the places is the time difference between them.
So, in the question, the time difference between Belem and Villamil is given by:

```
                     y= 7:06PM - 6:15PM
                     y= 51 minutes
```

To solve the given problem we need to know the time taken for the sun to set in Belem after the airplane took off.This is calculated thus:

```
                       ∆t=6:15PM - 4:40PM
                       ∆t=1 hour and 35 minutes 

 Which can also be written as ∆t =95 minutes.
```

Therefore, the sun sets 95 minutes after the airplane takes off from Belem.
Assuming the airplane travels at constant speed it covers equal times differences (time differences are proportional to distance covered) in equal times.
Given that the actual time taken to travel from Belem to Villamil is x;

```
               x= 4 hours - y
               x=4(60 minutes) - 51 minutes
               x=189 minutes.

When travelling for 189 minutes, the airplane covered a time difference of 51 minutes.

  In travelling for 95 minutes it will cover a time difference of: (95/189) × 51 minutes
                   =25 minutes and 38 seconds

   Thus, 

         Total time taken for the sun to set=Actual time taken + Time difference covered

      Total time taken = 95 minutes + 25minutes 38 seconds

       Total time taken = 120 minutes and 38 seconds

         Total time taken=2 hours and 38 seconds
                              =2 hours and 1 minute (approx.)
```

So we add 2 hours and 1 minute to the time the airplane takes off at Belem to get the time the sun sets on the journey.

```
  Time the sun sets=4:40PM + 2 hours and 1 minute
                                  =6:41PM.

  Therefore, the passengers see the sun set at 6:41PM.
```

Comment: Actuslly, the two places are 3 time zones apart and not 51 minutes. Today, the difference between the sunset in the two locations is just 10 minutes, according to Google. Something is wrong with your assumptions.